# How can I edit someone's question to apply whitespace formatting?

Tags: discussion, support

When I'm reading posted questions, sometimes I'll come across a question that has poorly formatted code:

while (true) {
  // do some stuff
  if (1) {
    break;
  }
}

This is easily corrected with the addition of whitespace:

```
while (true) {
  // do some stuff
  if (1) {
    break;
  }
}
```

However, I'm unable to commit this edit change to someone else's post because it is fewer than 6 characters. In these cases, I'm not looking to earn points for a "fantastic edit", I just want the question to be better formatted so it's clearer. I would be happy with a zero point review as long as the edit gets applied and the source is formatted correctly.

What can I do in order to edit posts in this case?

Comment: Are you sure nothing else can be improved in the question? If it lacks proper formatting, a question usually have some other things that can be improved.

Comment: I haven't been contributing to stackoverflow for that long, so I'm not sure. I haven't yet attempted to reword or clarify questions. The one thing that I do feel confident with, however, is formatting code so it appears like code.

Comment: If you can link the question you're referring to, we'll be able to show you what could be improved.

Comment: For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26662017/how-not-to-include-to-many-to-many-with-attribute

Comment: Yuck. Re-formatting that one won't help much I'm afraid. Got any better examples?

Comment: Sometimes a short answer is appropriate. Like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31508921/4447998. (OT: the review page suggests this answer is the only answer posted to that question, which is not really productive in this case.)